# Multi insert with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying insert multi values with pdo but I getting error,it looks like it takes the last value from the last column in `bindParam` and puts it for all columns:

```
    //Prepare query and execute it
    public function prepareMultiInsert($table = null, $columns = array(), $values = array(), $execute = false){
        $qr = "INSERT INTO `$table`(";
        //Keys
        foreach ($columns as $i => $column){
            $qr .= "`$column`, ";
        }

        $qr = substr($qr, 0, strlen($qr)-2) .  ") VALUES";

        foreach($values as $i => $v){
            $qr .= "(";
            //Values
            foreach ($v as $index => $value){
                $qr .= ":{$columns[$index]}$i, ";
            }

            $qr = substr($qr, 0, strlen($qr)-2) . "), ";
        }

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare(substr($qr, 0, strlen($qr)-2));

        foreach($values as $i => $v){
            //BindValues
            foreach ($v as $index => $value){
                $stmt->bindParam($columns[$index] . $i, $value);
            }
        }

        if($execute) return $this->queryInsert($stmt, true);
        else return $stmt;
    }

    //Execute
    public function queryInsert($stmt = null, $withIdReturn = false){   
        if($withIdReturn){
            if($stmt->execute()) return new returnDb(true, $this->conn->lastInsertId(), null, $stmt->queryString);
            else return new returnDb(false, null, $this->getError($stmt), $stmt->queryString);
        }else return new returnDb($stmt->execute(), null, $this->getError($stmt), $stmt->queryString);
    }
```

When I execute it like this:

```
$db->prepareMultiInsert("teste", ['id', 'name', 'age'], 
                                    [['1', 'woton', '19'],
                                    ['2', 'anita', '45'],
                                    ['3', 'jose', '13']], true));
```

ReturnDb return it:

```
object(returnDb)#5 (5) {
  ["return"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["result"]=>
  NULL
  ["query"]=>
  string(123) "INSERT INTO `teste`(`id`, `name`, `age`) VALUES(:id0, :name0, :age0), (:id1, :name1, :age1), (:id2, :name2, :age2)"
  ["error"]=>
  string(38) "Duplicate entry '13' for key 'PRIMARY'"
  ["fullError"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "23000"
    [1]=>
    int(1062)
    [2]=>
    string(38) "Duplicate entry '13' for key 'PRIMARY'"
  }
}
```

In table I have it:

[image]

He is catching last *age* and put in all columns on bind. Can anyone help me find the reason for the problem?

Comment: This is probably because you're binding a param (variable), which you keep updating, instead of the value of the variable at that time. You could give [bindValue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) a try.

Comment: @Jonnix Dude, now that you said I got it ... Ty, that's probably it, let me change and test here

Comment: @Jonnix That's right, lol, thank you very much